# How to make a separate footnote for a table's whole row with gtsummary?

Tags: gtsummary

I'm trying to add a footnote to a row of a gtsummary table, but I can't figure out how to do it for the whole row to describe summary statistics, separate from p_values.

```
library(gtsummary)
mtcars %>% 
  tbl_summary(by=am,
                 include = c( cyl, disp, drat, hp, mpg, qsec, vs, wt),
                 statistic = list(mpg  ~"{mean} ({sd})",
                                  wt  ~ "{sum} ({median})")
  ) %>% 
  add_overall() %>%
  add_p() %>%  
  bold_p() %>% 
  separate_p_footnotes()
```

I want to have a new number for:

"mpg":Mean (SD)

"wt": Sum (Median)

Answer (score 1):

The `add_stat_label()` function provides a few other options from a combined footnote listing all the summary statistics found in the table.

https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_stat_label.html

None of those options are exactly what you're asking for, however. The best way to get what you're requesting is to convert the gtsummary table to a gt table with `as_gt()`, then take advantage of the functions available in gt to place the footnotes precisely where you'd like them.